# Devise Timeout Working, but Not Redirecting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, timeout

I have setup up the `:timeoutable` and set the preferences for my development environment and production. The timeout is working perfectly except that it isn't redirecting to the signin page. For testing I've set the timeout to 10 seconds.

If I log in, wait 10 seconds, nothing happens. If I reload the page, it will load the same page but I won't be logged in.

Answer (score 6):

In the past, a Devise timeout would always redirect back to the sign in page.  But people found this confusing.  The idea was that if a user was on a page that didn't require a sign in, when the timeout occurred the user should be allowed to remain there.  [This customization](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Do-not-redirect-to-login-page-after-session-timeout) was the recommended way to get this behavior.

The default timeout behavior was documented as a bug in [Issue #1596](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1596) and [this commit](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/commit/275c480f89f814af7135093a507ab57397729faf) made a change so that timeouts would try to stay on the current page.

When a timeout occurs, the [timeoutable](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/hooks/timeoutable.rb) code throws a `timeout` message and the [FailureApp](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/failure_app.rb) class uses the `redirect_url` method to decide where to redirect to.  If you would always like to redirect to the sign in page, you can override the `redirect_url` method:

In `config/initializers/devise.rb` set up these lines within the `Devise.setup do |config| ... end` block:

```
require "custom_failure_app"

config.warden do |manager|
  manager.failure_app = CustomFailureApp
end
```

Create a new file at `lib/custom_failure_app.rb` with the following code:

```
class CustomFailureApp < Devise::FailureApp
  def redirect_url
    scope_url  # Always redirect to signin page
  end
end
```

Note that `scope_path` was changed to `scope_url` in [this commit](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/commit/a38f2f96b5e79af757682c74d2f5dfb136281bd5#diff-c1be825bdb5f3160081e41432f83d0d7).  So depending upon how recently you've updated your devise gem you may need to change this.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response! I did try this, however it didn't work as expected. The issue for me specifically I believe is that the redirect isn't firing at all. The page just sits there, even if the `:timeout` action has fired.

Comment: In the `CustomFailureApp` class, if you add a method called `respond` with one line that calls `puts` to log a debug message to the console and a second line that calls `super` to fire the standard respond logic, does your debug line get called?

Comment: @cschroed I have the same problem, the debug line only gets called when i manually refresh the page. So class is loaded, session is timing out as expected but does not redirect to login page.